# Download apps to 1st gen ipad

Tags: ipad

I bought my Mom a 1st gen for Mothers day.  But now I cannot get any apps! 
Any help would be appreciated. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: A 1st gen iPad is rather old, I assume you've bought it second-hand. Can you add some details about the situation: Do you not know which app to start to access the App Store, do you not find the apps you are looking for, do you have trouble setting up an account?

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141840/finding-old-versions-of-ios-apps-for-5-1-1-on-a-1st-generation-ipad?rq=1, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201383/install-new-apps-on-ipad-1st-first-generation-with-max-ios-5-1-1?rq=1, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201416/finding-old-version-of-ios-apps-for-a-1st-generation-ipad-running-ios-5-1-1?rq=1

Comment: Generally, the App Store lets you download older versions of apps (if they exist) that may still be compatible with your device.

Answer (score 1):

A first-generation iPad only supports iOS 5. That means it only runs apps that still support iOS 5, which are few and far between.

To download these apps, head to the App Store (the blue icon on the iPad's home screen), and you'll be able to download apps. Either they'll download or give you an error that they're not supported, in which case you can't download them.